# Why does Goku wear a different Gi in DBGT?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

I've always wondered why he changed his gi to a blue top, white belt, and yellow pants. Is this perhaps due Akira Toriyama never creating the actual DBGT series? If so, is there an substantial evidence?

[image]

Comment: i don't think there could be a reason for this.
If u go to see the attire, then probably everyones appearance has changed in DBGT!

Comment: because he's a kid this time so his old clothes wont fit and who would be able to tailor his old kids cloathes

Comment: He wore both the purple gi as well as the orange one when he was a kid. And in DBZ, people also managed to magically change gi appearances, like King Kai and Picollo.

Comment: He could have taken Goten's clothes acutally. It'd have fit him exactly. It just seems to be a technical miss from the makers and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

He wore this even during the last episodes of dragon ball z when he went off to train with Uub so think it just continued from there.

Comment: It's actually a little bit different

Answer (score 0):

The new Gi was introduced at the end of DBZ to show that a lot of time had passed.

Then, not only was the Gi different but also significant events had taken place such as Gohan's marriage and Pan's birth.

Also almost everyone's outfit was changed. This was probably done to show that a long period of peace had prevailed and so the characters didn't need to wear their fighting clothes (or armor as in Vegeta's case) all the time.

When DBGT came along it maintained a similar style to these end episodes of DBZ to show continuity, with some changes which was the liberty of the studio/animators making it.